# Errors while fine tuning InceptionV3 in Keras

Tags: keras

I am going to fine-tune InceptionV3 model using my self-defined dataset. Unfortunately, when using model.fit to train, here comes the error below:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Firstly, I load my own dataset as training_data which contains a pair of image and corresponding label. Then, I use the code below to convert them into specific array-type(img_new and label_new) so that it's compatible to Keras's inputs of both data and labels.

```
for img, label in training_data:    

    img_new[i,:,:,:] = img
    label_new[i,:] = label
    i=i+1
```

Second, I fine tune the Inception Model below.

```
InceptionV3_model=keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=False, 
                                                              weights='imagenet', 
                                                              input_tensor=None, 
                                                              input_shape=None, 
                                                              pooling=None, 
                                                              classes=1000)

#InceptionV3_model.summary()

    # add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = InceptionV3_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 4 classes
predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=InceptionV3_model.input, outputs=predictions)

    # Transfer Learning
for layer in model.layers[:311]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[311:]:
    layer.trainable = True

    from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=3, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

Does anyone have ideas of what is wrong while training using model.fit?

Sincerely thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Are your labels are sparse? If so, this caused the issue. sparse_categorical_crossentropy or change your labels shape to match the prediction.

Comment: What is the shape of `y_train`?  Please, post `y_train` exapmle and `y_train.shape` (if it's a numpy array) - looks like it's not a binary vectors, but class label digits (but the model expects first option)

Comment: @Amir  You r so amazing!!! It is because my labels r integers when categorical_crossentropy is substituted by sparse_categorical_crossentropy, the problem is solved! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Happy that it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because my labels r integers, I gotta compile it by sparse_categorical_crossentropy which is set for integer labels instead of categorical_crossentropy which is used for one-hot encoding.

Sincerely thank for the help by @Amir very much. :-)